# Accessing child object in nested form during edit - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I'm sure this is simple but I can't seem to find a solution and I'm sure others will benefit from this question.

I have a nested form with:

```
has_many :children
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children

belongs_to :parent
```

I have a nested form setup as follows which is creating and editing parent and multiple children perfectly however to improve usability I want to access some variables in the child object during edit. I'm using a rails scaffold so this is the same form for both my new and edit actions.

```
<%= form_for(@parent, :html => {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>

  Parent form stuff here

  <%= f.fields_for :children, @parent.children do |c| %>

    Child form stuff here

    I WANT TO ACCESS CHILD OBJECT HERE DURING EDIT eg c.foo

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

By this I want to access something like c.foo, child.foo or @parent.child.foo or similar.

It would also be great if I could access the index for the children as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails form helpers, `object` is used to access the underlying object.

In your example, you should be able to access a child's `foo` variable within your `fields_for` block by calling `c.object.foo`.